# How to style an XML file with namespaces

Tags: css, xml

I created an XML file with some namespaces, like this :

```
<root 
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

I now want to style this XML using a simple CSS file, and be able to separate the namespaces to style them differently, but I didn't find the answer anywhere.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@namespace html url(http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/);
@namespace furn url(https://www.w3schools.com/furniture);

html|table {
    color: green;
}

furn|table {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.