# Styling XML tags

Tags: css, xml

Test.css

```
xliff{ font-family: "Segoe UI", Roboto; font-size:12pt; line-height:1.5; background-color: red;}
xliff{ margin-top:2cm; margin-left:2cm; margin-right:2cm; }
sdl{display:none}
body{display:table}
internal-file{display:none}
header{display:none}
sdl\:value{color: blue;}
sdl\:seg{display:none}
source{display:none}
trans-unit{display:table-row}
seg-source {display:table-cell; color: lightblue;padding:10px;  }
target {display:table-cell; color: yellowgreen; padding:10px;  }
trans-unit { 
    width: 100%;
}
sdl\:prev-origin {display:none}
```

It does not seem to have the desired result as the content of sdl.value is still displayed.
The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="test.css"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0">

<trans-unit translate="no" id="af0f31bf-03a4-4d49-a0ce-6815839dde15"><source><x id="745"/><x id="746"/></source></trans-unit><trans-unit id="972be2b5-0e6b-4d2c-9b53-e18163f21692"><source><g id="747">Der benötigte Adapter ist im Lieferumfang enthalten. Die notwendige Düse ist auf den entsprechenden Hochdruckreiniger abgestimmt und muss separat bestellt werden.</g></source><seg-source><g id="747"><mrk mtype="seg" mid="18">Der benötigte Adapter ist im Lieferumfang enthalten.</mrk> <mrk mtype="seg" mid="19">Die notwendige Düse ist auf den entsprechenden Hochdruckreiniger abgestimmt und muss separat bestellt werden.</mrk></g></seg-source><target><g id="747"><mrk mtype="seg" mid="18">The required adapter is not included in the scope of delivery.</mrk> <mrk mtype="seg" mid="19">The required nozzle has been adjusted to suit the corresponding high pressure cleaner and must be ordered separately.</mrk></g></target><sdl:seg-defs><sdl:seg id="18" conf="Translated" origin="interactive" percent="71"><sdl:prev-origin origin="tm" origin-system="Kaercher_350510001_de-div_Kaercher_de-DE_en-GB" percent="71"><sdl:prev-origin/><sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">HytyTbMpE4BBQ2HL2EQnDHYx3kgA=</sdl:value></sdl:prev-origin><sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">HytyTbMpE4BBQ2HL2EQnDHYx3kg=</sdl:value><sdl:value key="SDL:ProjectTranslationHash">-1694672644</sdl:value></sdl:seg><sdl:seg id="19" conf="Translated" origin="interactive" percent="85"><sdl:prev-origin origin="tm" origin-system="Kaercher_350510001_de-div_Kaercher_de-DE_en-GB" percent="85"><sdl:prev-origin/><sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">nmZoPCFNuuN00Vm6It3Pe5HD7A8=</sdl:value></sdl:prev-origin><sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">nmZoPCFNuuN00Vm6It3Pe5HD7A8=</sdl:value><sdl:value key="SDL:ProjectTranslationHash">261709337</sdl:value></sdl:seg></sdl:seg-defs></trans-unit><trans-unit translate="no" id="d37518d3-0651-4090-9b6d-9b83abc9a98e"><source><x id="748"/><x id="749"/><x id="750"/><x id="751"/><x id="752"/><x id="753"/><x id="754"/><x id="755"/><x id="756"/></source></trans-unit><trans-unit id="b3f8bb44-053c-4374-8c05-466c5a3506ca"><source>Heißwasser Hochdruckreiniger</source><seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="20">Heißwasser Hochdruckreiniger</mrk></seg-source><target><mrk mtype="seg" mid="20">Hot water high-pressure cleaner</mrk></target><sdl:seg-defs><sdl:seg id="20" conf="Translated" origin="interactive" percent="65"><sdl:prev-origin origin="tm" origin-system="Kaercher_350510001_de-div_Kaercher_de-DE_en-GB" percent="65"><sdl:prev-origin/><sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">TsebFOhH0ch7L/nKx8LMRBnOmzo=</sdl:value></sdl:prev-origin><sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">TsebFOhH0ch7L/nKx8LMRBnOmzo=</sdl:value><sdl:value key="SDL:ProjectTranslationHash">1973989304</sdl:value></sdl:seg></sdl:seg-defs></trans-unit>
```

Comment: Post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118821/how-to-style-an-xml-file-with-namespaces

Comment: Please don't try and _edit_ people's answers, if what was suggested doesn't work for you or you have questions for clarification - _comment_ under the answer instead, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `sdl:value{display:none;}`

The colon has special meaning in CSS selector syntax - it indicates that what follows, is a pseudo class.

You want the colon to be part of the tagname of the namespaced element you are trying to select here though, so you need to escape it using a backslash:

```
sdl\:value{display:none;}
```

Comment: Sticking XML into a jsfiddle is not the best way of testing, but you can see here that it should work in theory: https://jsfiddle.net/t1bwfhv6/

Comment: cant argue with your answer, even if it doesnt work with the file I have. Thanks will continue to investigate

Comment: Cache problem maybe? If you updated the CSS file, and then reload the XML, the browser might still take the stylesheet from cache.

Answer (score 0):

give your sdls an id and then apply

`#YourIdName{ display:none; }`

should be good ;)